# Why was the Minotaur V built as a 5-stage design?

Tags: rockets, solid-fuel, stages

Why is Orbital Science's [Minotaur V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minotaur_V) rocket a five stage design? I am aware this is derived from an ICBM design, but why would anyone want a five stage design for launching non-lethal payloads? It seems to me that additional stages only open more opportunity for problems and thus mission failure.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's always easier to create a new launcher by making a small modification to a reliable existing launcher. Small solid rocket stages are relatively simple and reliable, so building up a launcher from solids is less risky than the stage count might indicate. Small solid stages are also extremely cheap.

The [Peacekeeper ICBM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGM-118_Peacekeeper) is a three-stage suborbital rocket. By replacing its warhead payload with a fourth stage which could insert a payload into low Earth orbit, the [Minotaur IV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minotaur_IV) was created. Two different solid rocket motors were used for the upper stage, the Orion 38 and the Star 48. The [Star 48](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_(rocket_stage)#Star_48) in particular has a very long operational history going back to the 1980s; [Orion 38](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orion_(rocket_stage)) was 20 years old when Minotaur IV was first flown, so both of these are proven stages. Minotaur IV has 5 successful launches under its belt -- not a long track record, but validating the principle.

Minotaur V extended Minotaur IV by adding a Star 37 to propel a payload out of low Earth orbit to GTO or to the moon. The Star 37 has an even longer history than the Star 48, so again this is a low-risk modification to the launcher.